# Angular resource call not fired when called from $scope.$watch

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I created a directive that watches for a `day` attribute and retrieves a remote resource whenever the attribute value changes. CoffeeScript code :

```
angular.module('app.directives').directive 'myDirective', ['$timeout', ($timeout)->

    DirectiveController=($scope, activityResource)->

        # Load activities
        load= ()->
            activityResource.get {
                day: $scope.day
                environment_id: $scope.environment.id
            },
            (data)->
                $scope.activities = data.activities

        # Watch environment and reload activities
        $scope.$watch 'environment', (value) ->
            load()

        # Watch selected day to reload activities
        $scope.$watch 'day', (value) ->
            load()
...
]
```

The `load` method is called each time the `day` changes but the result callback never triggers. Network inspection shows that the request is not sent to the remote end. The only workaround I found is to defer the execution of the `load` method using the `$timeout` service :

```
        $scope.$watch 'day', (value) ->
            $timeout (()-> load()), 10
```

I suspect an issue related to the scope lifecycle but I could not figure it out why I had to defer the call to the resource.

**Update** :

The resource source code :

```
resources = angular.module('app.resources', ['ngResource'])

...

resources.factory 'app.activityResource', ['$resource', 'app.endpoint', ($resource, endpoint)->
  $resource "#{endpoint()}/user/environments/:environment_id/activities/:id/:verb",
  {environment_id: "@environment_id", id: "@id"},
  latest:
    method : 'GET'
    params:
      verb: 'latest'
  annual:
    method : 'GET'
    params:
      verb: 'annual'
]
```

I also added to the code excerpt the second watched attribute (`environment`) used as a parameter to query the resource.

**Update 2**

I don't know if it is related but we're using CORS to access the remote end (which seems to work well).

Comment: Is it possible for you to put your code in plunkr or jsfiddle. Simpler demo for debugging code.

Comment: What does your activityResource look like ?

Comment: @RishabhSinghal I tried to create a jsFiddle but have not managed to reproduce the issue so far.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue with a simplified version of $resource, and it seems to work and call it everytime, http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/qUHGY/4/ .

Comment: Same here, I have not been able to reproduce the issue with a simplified version. http://jsfiddle.net/jefmathiot/xCJjc/ We're trying to isolate parts which may collide but haven't managed to spot the issue.

Comment: As added in my second update we use CORS to access the remote end. But I don't think it is related to our issue.

Comment: I tried the same jsFiddle with a cross origin request and it seems to work properly. I tried to modify the jsFiddle to be closer to our structure http://jsfiddle.net/jefmathiot/xCJjc/4/ (one directive nested in another) but we still fail to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you aren't seeing a request fired off is that as part of the $http call, the config is passed around to each interceptor as a promise.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/b99d064b6ddbcc9f59ea45004279833e9ea82928/src/ng/http.js#L665-L670

In angular, $q promises are only resolved at the beginning of a $digest cycle.  As a result, your HTTP request won't even be fired off until a $digest cycle happens, which is why you're seeing that wrapping a $timeout around it helps ( a timeout causes a $digest ).

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/2a5c3555829da51f55abd810a828c73b420316d3/src/ng/q.js#L160
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/3967f5f7d6c8aa7b41a5352b12f457e2fbaa251a/src/ng/rootScope.js#L503-L516

You can also verify this by re-creating the error condition you're seeing and watching network requests.  After you run this, you should see your request fire off:

```
angular.element( "[ng-app]" ).scope().$digest()
```

That code fires off a $digest cycle on the $rootScope, causing your unresolved promises to become resolved.

See this issue for more discussion, because I agree that this is surprising behavior.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2881

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I suspected this kind of issue. Do you have an idea why it works in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jefmathiot/xCJjc/4/ ? I tried to be really close to our real use case (a click in a directive that changes a property in of the nested directive which fires an Ajax call) but I can't understand why in this particular case the $digest cycle is executed.

Comment: I'm in the realm of guessing without seeing your exact source, but if you look at the link I posted to the rootScope source, you can see that the asyncQueue is being processed as a part of the do/while loop in the $digest.  That actually means that if your scope isn't the last scope that processed, you may see that it works as expected.  If it IS the last scope that's processed, the asyncQueue won't be drained until the next $digest

Comment: It seems that you guess pretty well :), but I'm a bit lost. In the rootScope source code, the do-while loop seems to be processed as long as there are elements into the asyncQueue. Calling a resource isn't supposed to append an element into this queue ?

Comment: The do/while is associated with doing dirty checking on each $scope ( see the while conditions ), however at the beginning of each iteration, the asyncQueue is emptied.  Each scope shares the same asyncQueue since they all inherit from the $rootScope.  If your $scope is the last one being processed in the $digest cycle, it will add something to the asyncQueue for your deferred to be resolved, however it won't be drained until a $digest happens again.  Hopefully that clarifies the case that I *think* may be happening.  You could always run a debugger and watch the asyncQueue to see what happens

Comment: I ran the debugger (without the `$timeout` hack). When the `day` property changes : first `$digest` with asyncQueue empty, then call to the resource from the `load` method, then second `$digest` with the asyncQueue still empty...

Comment: Into the `$digest` method after calling the resource, `this.$$asyncQueue` returns an empty array where `this.$root.$$asyncQueue` contains the actual call to the resource. I could misunderstand this PR but it seems that it's supposed to fix the kind of issue I'm facing https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/331cd5a8cb5efdafe8ad7eb386aed4033cfc1bb3